# Get length of array passed into a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

How can I pass an array into a function and retain information about its length without passing the length separately?

[self Q&A - better answers than mine below]

Comment: Here - http://bit.ly/1kQCzFI

Comment: I know the traditional ways of doing it, but I think I have a useful workaround, posted below. I don't think any of the people downvoting have looked at and/or tried running my solution.

Comment: Why did you ask the question, only to 2 seconds later provide your own answer?  Further, your answer is incorrect, by virtue of providing the static number of 10 in as a parameter, you aren't dealing with getting the size of an arbitrary sized array anyway, you are dealing with the routine already knowing the size because you have statically provided it, further your question is vague to talk about arrays, but what you really wanted was an array of chars, which if used like a string than, strlen will work.

Comment: @trumpetlicks http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Diti - True, and I have indeed done this, but this question also already has many answers here at SO and other places on the web, so if all this OP is doing is to post QA to gain points, that's outside the realm of what SO is about.  Also the OPs answer IS NOT correct for the question asked.  The other 2 answers below are correct, C does not allow for array sizes to be known unless explicitly passed in.  This is WHY the secure versions of many routines are written today the way they are, to EXPLICETLY pass in a size parameter.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius "_I don't think any of the people downvoting have looked at and/or tried running my solution._" there's another option: people may have looked at it and known that it works as you describe, but felt it to actually be a worthless solution. I am not one of your downvoters, but I do feel this way.

Comment: Take my advice and delete this question.

Comment: @mah, I appreciate your honesty and I respect your downvote. @ alk, I'm going to leave it up, because although it reflects poorly on me to have so many downvotes, I think my answer is useful in a limited way, and others such as haacks, have posted useful information.

I hope that someone will upvote this question if only for the other answers below.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius I didn't downvote, I just don't disagree with them.

Comment: I do not see the use of creating a function to return a value already known, that is 10. So it's not the downvotes degrading you, but the (missing?) idea behind this approach.

Comment: @ alk, it's simply if you're going to do bounds checking that this allows you to do that without passing another (possibly incorrect) parameter. But I agree that someone who could correctly implement my method probably won't have a use for it and vice versa.

Comment: Why not just do `const size_t myarrayssize = 10;` or `#define MYARRAYSSIZE ((size_t) (10))`?

Comment: Or create a struct incapsulating the array and it's size, like `struct myarraydesc {size_t s; char a[10];} = {10, "123456789"};`

Comment: @trumpetlicks, I wasn't posting to gain points. (As evidenced by my not deleting my -3 question in shame.) I was posting because I thought my answer could be interesting and useful to others. As has been pointed out already, the use case for it is so limited that it's not worth much, other than as an oddity. I honestly couldn't care less about points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C, arrays can't be passed entirely to a function and hence it is not possible. When you pass an array name then it decays to pointer to the first element. Using `sizeof` operator would not help you in any way because it will give you the size of pointer.

Either you pass the size of array to the function or use a *sentinel* value at the end of array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int size(int *a)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(*a++ != -1)
        count++;
    return count + 1;
}
int main(void)
{
    signed int a[] = { 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, -1};

    printf("size of array is: %d\n", size(a));
}
```

Comment: +1 for sentinel as I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: @eckes; Yes. This is the only way :)

Comment: not the only. the answer of Ashalynd is valid as well.

Comment: @eckes in AmadeusDrZaius's defense, his answer is valid for his use case. The problem is his use case is not one anyone ever has a problem with, rather the more general use case that you and others have answered is the real problem people ask about.

Comment: OT: However, it's still `int main(void)` at least. And memory/arrays sizes should better be typed `size_t` not `int`.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK If you pass an array as a pointer, there is no way to know its length in C. The length has to be provided by the caller.

Comment: ... or one uses a special end-of-array marker (such as a NULL pointer)

Comment: +1 for passing length. Best would be to merge this answer and the one given by haccks.

Comment: @eckes, I gave haccks the check since his/her already included this. They're both good answers though.

Answer (score 3):

Summing things up:

- either provide a [sentinel value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22403395/520162) that marks the end of the array
- or [pass the size of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22403282/520162) to the callee

The only two methods that actually work.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the length separately, like many do. Another perhaps impractical way is that you could pass a pointer to the array itself and retrieve the length from there.

**EDIT #2:** Removed the version with the global variable since it's bad practice. I'm reposting the old solution, which though rigid was less tedious and less dangerous.

**EDIT #3:** Replaced the original with something that at least shows how this could be useful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(char (*p)[10]);

int main(void){

    char p[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    printArray(&p);
    return 0;

}

void printArray(char (*p)[10]){

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof (*p); i++)
        printf("%d ", (*p)[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: `sizeof ( *p )` is **not** the size of the array you are passing as parameter

Comment: you are asking question and u only replying..weird?

Comment: I'm posting it as a self-Q&A. I can make that explicit in my question if you'd like, but I thought it was less cringey this way (though it will be a bit cringey any way I post it).

@Andreas, It is. Check it yourself by running the program. It prints 10.

Comment: Yes it certainly does, but then the whole function is *only* applicable for arrays of size 10, as it does **not** calculate the array size at runtime, but at compile time (from its parameter type `*p[10]`)

Comment: Yes, that's true. I'm only claiming that it's useful in that you don't have to pass the length explicitly, thus eliminating some sources of programmer error.

Comment: That's an elegant solution, though. Too bad it only works with arrays of same size.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius your premise for this self Q/A is flawed. It presumes it's a common (or even occasional) problem where this is needed and the array length is a known constant at build time (in this case, that constant being 10). That problem is not one people ask about... the question people ask about is when they have no way to know the answer at build time and want to know at run time.

Comment: +1 just for teaching me something that I didn't know... However, OP will have to declare the function itself with the actual size of the array, so your solution does little in actually solving the problem at hand.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius: this answer is ridiculous! It is not useful at all. If you know that the array is 10 large, you don't need a function. If it's not 10 large, it doesn't work.

Comment: `You can pass the length separately, like many do. Or... you could pass a pointer to the array itself and retrieve the length from there.` That is two completely different things (runtime vs. compile time)

Comment: @eckes, I posted a new version which allows you to use the function repeatedly for arrays of different lengths, as long as you take the time to code the length variable before passing it in. The advantage is not in speed, but in reducing programmer error and allowing bounds checking of statically allocated arrays.

Comment: `but in reducing programmer error` - by adding a global variable? Come on ...

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius: doesn't help. This is a flavour of passing in the array size to the calculating function.

Comment: Do not use global variable.

Comment: @eckes Well, if you use the previous way I posted of hardcoding the 10 into the function, then you don't need to include the length every time. But obviously in order to have some range of inputs, you do. So in either situation there will be drawbacks, but that's true of anything in C. I'm just posting this as a possible alternative, not as an end-all be-all of solutions. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Using a global as length specifier is a just a dirty way of passing the length.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius your first solution was at least acceptable in its extremely limited use case. This global-based solution is absolutely horrible and I can easily break it with multithreaded code. `unsigned long arraySize(char *p; size_t length);` is the **only** valid way to solve this with a generic array, and providing the sentinel that eckes suggests is also reasonable.

Comment: In response to the righteous outcry about the version with the global variable `length`, I've moved the solution back to what it was originally. I guess I learned today that I'm a populist.

Comment: @eckes, I edited my post to at least show how it could be useful (though in a very, very limited context).